# add a info bar under the Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to know how I could add a bar that would contain something like a crumb trail you get on websites. kinda like this (where the info bar would be the Navigation bar, the bar with  would be my sub bar and the calendar would be a tableview).

[image]

Okat so I hope this is still making sense. But this is pretty much what I would like to do... I am woundering the best way to do it?

would I just change my uitableviewcontroller into a normal view (window) with a toolbar on it? then put the tableview inside the window and then just push that onto the nav stack? I'm not sure but hopefully someone here has a better idea than me and can help me out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UINavigationController has a toolbar that is disabled by default. Enable it with the following:

```
- (void)setToolbarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Then you could add UIToolbarButtons and adjust its frame as needed.

But I recommend keeping the toolbar at the bottom for proper usability.  People don't like accidentally hitting things they didn't mean to because the placement of buttons are too close.

Comment: is there a way to have it display at the top right under the Navigation bar. I think possibly I will have to do something custom, because I am only going to have text in it, which represent the users previous selection something like **ball>small** they wont be selectable they are purerly there to show the user their selection and what the current data in the uitableview represents.

Comment: @C.Johns You should be able to adjust the toolbar's frame before enabling it, something like its origin to (0,0) and keeping its size the same.

I recommend rethinking how you are laying out these controls and labels though.  It kinda sounds like you should be setting a title for what the user selected and then have your controls in the UIToolbar.

Comment: okay cool thanks very much, I have checked your answer as correct, I;ll get onto the rest..

Answer (score 0):

Hum, not sure to follow you perfectly here, but you CAN add anything (including your infobar) in the top of a UITableViewController, since there's a Header UIView as well as a Footer one (just try to drag in IB something just above your tableview).

Hope it helps.